# How do you format text from a file when reading the file into a text box in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating an Inventory project in python using tkinter and one of the things I want it to do is display the entire inventory that is stored in a text file. So far I have it working but the format of the text after its read onto the frame is not aligned and doesn't look great.

[image: The numbers aren't aligned correctly]

```
def openFile():
                tf = filedialog.askopenfilename(
                        initialdir="C:/Users/MainFrame/Desktop/", 
                        title="Open Text file", 
                        filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),)
        )  
                tf = open(tf)  # or tf = open(tf, 'r')
                data = tf.read()
                self.txtInventory.insert(END, data)
                tf.close()


if __name__=='__main__':
        root=Tk()
        application= Inventory(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using a fixed width font?

Comment: I have but I'm not sure I'm giving the right argument in the right place I tried 
    'self.txtInventory.insert(END, data, font='TkFixedFont)'

Comment: `self.txtInventory.insert(END, data, font='TkFixedFont)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would use tags for formatting:

```
from tkinter import *
 
root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x250+800+50')

txtInventory = Text(root, wrap='word', padx=10, pady=10)
txtInventory.pack(fill='both', padx=10, pady=10)
txtInventory.tag_config('fixed', font='TkFixedFont')    # Fixed style
#             Tag name ----^
txtInventory.tag_add('fixed', '1.0', 'end') # Apply to entire text

# Insert example text
contents = '''ItemName    Qty     Bay#

Bleach       17       4
Towels       20       3'''
txtInventory.insert('end', contents)

root.mainloop()
```

Have a look at [Tkinter Text Styles Demo](https://pyinmyeye.blogspot.com/2012/08/tkinter-text-styles-demo.html)